# How to ensure outer join with filter still returns all desired rows?

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

Imagine I have two tables in a DB like so:

```
products:    
product_id  name
----------------
1           Hat
2           Gloves
3           Shoes

sales:
product_id  store_id  sales
----------------------------
1           1         20
2           2         10
```

Now I want to do a query to list ALL products, and their sales, for store_id = 1. My first crack at it would be to use a left join, and filter to the store_id I want, or a null store_id, in case the product didn't get any sales at store_id = 1, since I want all the products listed:

```
SELECT name, coalesce(sales, 0)
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sales s ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE store_id = 1 or store_id is null;
```

Of course, this doesn't work as intended, instead I get:

```
name   sales
---------------
Hat    20
Shoes  0
```

No Gloves! This is because Gloves did get sales, just not at store_id = 1, so the WHERE clause has filtered them out.

How then can I get a list of ALL products and their sales for a specific store?

Here are some queries to create the test tables:

```
create temp table test_products as 
select 1 as product_id, 'Hat' as name;
insert into test_products values (2, 'Gloves');
insert into test_products values (3, 'Shoes');
create temp table test_sales as
select 1 as product_id, 1 as store_id, 20 as sales;
insert into test_sales values (2, 2, 10);
```

UPDATE: I should note that I am aware of this solution:

```
SELECT name, case when store_id = 1 then sales else 0 end as sales
FROM test_products p
LEFT JOIN test_sales s ON p.product_id = s.product_id;
```

however, it is not ideal... in reality I need to create this query for a BI tool in such a way that the tool can simply add a where clause to the query and get the desired results. Inserting the required store_id into the correct place in this query is not supported by this tool. So I'm looking for other options, if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the WHERE condition to the `LEFT JOIN` clause to prevent that rows go missing.

```
SELECT p.name, coalesce(s.sales, 0)
FROM   products p
LEFT   JOIN sales s ON p.product_id = s.product_id
                   AND s.store_id = 1;
```

#### Edit for additional request:

I assume you can manipulate the SELECT items? Then this should do the job:

```
SELECT p.name
      ,CASE WHEN s.store_id = 1 THEN coalesce(s.sales, 0) ELSE NULL END AS sales
FROM   products p
LEFT   JOIN sales s USING (product_id)
```

<sub>Also simplified the join syntax in this case.</sub>

Comment: Ah, of course. Silly of me to miss that. Unfortunately it still doesn't solve my problem entirely. As per the update to the question, I am trying to write this query for a BI tool in such a way that it can dynamically add the WHERE clause. Is there any other way to approach it? (I will still accept this as the answer since it DOES answer the question I asked.)

Comment: @EvilPuppetMaster: see my amended answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not near SQL, but give this a shot:

```
SELECT name, coalesce(sales, 0)
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sales s ON p.product_id = s.product_id AND store_id = 1
```

You don't want a where on the whole query, just on your join

Comment: Oh the pain of answering a question first, but then having someone with more points give the same exact answer a minute later, appear higher on the list, and receive 2 up votes and the answer, while I receive nothing...